# Retrieving nodes and relationships from neo4j to R console as Dataframe

Tags: r, neo4j, r-neo4j

I have created the graph database using neo4j and from R i am trying to retrieve some results.
But the same "GeneName" nodes have many connections as shown in the attached image (From Neo4J).
So, is it possible to get the all the connections for the GeneName nodes as a dataframe on R console.

More detailed Information:

Genes information i took from one file and the connections around the GeneName nodes in the screenshot attached are considered from another file.
I have written cypher to connect the various files based on common gene names from all the files.
For example

file A (4 columns and many rows)

SCA1 info1 info2 info3

file B (4 columns and many rows)

info5 info7 info8 info10 SCA1

Now i have written a cypher query in a way that based on GeneName (SCA1) the two files are connected

The output after connecting the two files will be like

SCA1 info1 info2 info3 info5 info7 info8 info10

So in the screenshot, each GeneName node are connected to info1 info2 info3 info5 info7 info8 info10

Pavan Kumar Alluri
Senior Project Engineer
C-DAC KP
INDIA

![enter image description here][1]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3cwtskbd803cqjr/NIcole.png?dl=0

Comment: Can you provide sample data or a way to reproduce your graph along with what you want to see in your data.frame?

Comment: Hello Nicole
In the graph attached, genenamde nodes (CA1, CA3...) are connected to uniprot nodes (purple color) and many other nodes (dull white), each representing different information as shown in the legend.
So now in dataframe..I need the information in the following manner


https://www.dropbox.com/s/c6gw4wa9vc9jnj5/Book1.xlsx?dl=0

Thanks a lot for support

Pavan Kumar Alluri

Comment: I'm not sure I'll be able to help based on a picture, unfortunately. Can you provide an R script to reproduce what you have? Also, can you tell me exactly what you want in your data.frame? What should each column have? What have you tried that didn't work as you expected?

Comment: I just want to convert the graph into text format as shown in previous post.

match (n:`GeneName`) where n.GeneName="CA1" return n;
It gives the following graph (on Neo4j) https://www.dropbox.com/s/h28k141uhcv6mpl/DF.png?dl=0

The above graph showing relations with "CA1" genename node.

Now, if i want same thing on R console, I used following command

> getNodes(graph,'match (n:`GeneName`) return n limit 1')
[[1]]
$genename
[1] "CA1"

to get nodes.
But How will I get the relations of CA1 node on R console?

Thanks a lot for your kind support.

Comment: Hello Nicole,
I am using getRels in order to get relations of the node.
MATCH (a)-[:`GeneName`]->(b) RETURN a,b cypher is working on Neo4j but the same command on R says "The entity returned is not a relationship. Check that your query is returning a relationship."

Comment: getRels and getSingleRel are for retrieving relationships, as the error messages say. See the docs on getRels and getSingleRel. You should return the relationship, not the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few things:

```
ca1 = getSingleNode(graph, "MATCH (n:GeneName) WHERE n.name = 'CA1' RETURN n")
r = outgoingRels(ca1)
```

`r` is then a list of relationship objects. You can use endNode and startNode on these.

```
lapply(r, startNode)
lapply(r, endNode)
```

Or:

```
r = getRels(graph, "MATCH (n:GeneName)-[r]->() WHERE n.name = 'CA1' RETURN r")
```

This will also get a list of relationship objects, on which you can use the apply family of functions along with endNode and startNode.

You could also play with path objects:

```
query = "
MATCH p = (n:GeneName)-->()
WHERE n.name = 'CA1'
RETURN p
"

p = getPaths(graph, query)
n = lapply(p, nodes)
```

Of course, without any data to reproduce your graph I can't be certain which method is best. I strongly recommend reading through the [docs and examples](http://nicolewhite.github.io/RNeo4j/docs/).

Comment: ca1 = getSingleNode(graph, "MATCH (n:GeneName) WHERE n.name = 'CA1' RETURN n")
r = outgoingRels(ca1)

says "Error in outgoingRels.default(ca1) :
  Invalid object. Must supply node object."

Comment: What happens when you print ca1?

Comment: Hi Nicole,
ca1 = getSingleNode(graph, "MATCH (n:GeneName) WHERE n.name = 'CA1' RETURN n") r = outgoingRels(ca1) says "Error in outgoingRels.default(ca1) : Invalid object. Must supply node object." –

when i print ca1, it is showing NULL

Comment: I tried the following command  node1=getSingleNode(graph,query="match (n:GeneName) where n.GeneName='CA1' return n")  
> node1  
NULL  
But the cypher query in the neo4j is showing relations